# Циклические ссылки

Tags: javascript

При изучении **Json** столкнулся с термином **"избегайте циклических(круговых) ссылок"**,

но в самом материале нет ничего про циклические ссылки.

Если вас это не затруднит, то не могли бы вы пожалуйста показать

как выглядят
циклические ссылки и зачем их применяют?

Comment: экзземлпяр А  ссылается на экземпляр Б, а Б в свою очередь на А. специально их не применяют. Если сборщик мусора построен на подсчете ссылок, то такая конструкция обречена на вечную жизнь после удаления всех внешних ссылок на эту пару объектов. Так же из минусов потенциально можно уйти в рекурсию при какой-нибудь сериализации. Исходя из этих нюансов вам и рекомендуют избегать этих ситуаций

Comment: Простыми словами что такое сериализация в js?

Comment: сериализация - сохранение данных в некоторый формат для передачи, например, текстовый. JSON один из форматов обмена.

Comment: А на вики написано, что это процесс перевода какой-либо структуры данных в последовательность байтов.
Верно ли это утверждение?

Comment: любая информация это последовательность байт

Comment: @teran, объект тоже является последовательностью байтов без использования JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Вот циклическая ссылка:

```
let obj = {};
obj.a = obj;
```

где ключ объекта ссылается на сам объект.

Могут быть и более сложные ситуации, где много ключей ссылаются на какие-то другие ветки сложного объекта (о которых вы спросили в другом вопросе).

Нужно это тогда, когда в данных по логике вещей требуется сослаться на объект выше по цепочке вложенности. Например как тут:

```
let home: {
    owner: {
        name: 'Misha'
    }
}
home.owner.home = home; // У Миши дом такой, какой мы описали выше.
```

Comment: А зачем в конце писать = home ?
Мы же обращаемся к объекту и его свойству, зачем объект копировать в один и тот же объект?

Comment: Не проще ли написать home.owner.name ?

Comment: - Не проще ли искать потеряный кошелек под фонарем? - Проще, только его там нет.

Comment: Все равно пока не понимаю, что значит home.owner.home = home. 

Зачем два раза писать home через точку?

Comment: @Человек , "зачем объект копировать в один и тот же объект?" - почему в один и тот же, если точка стоит сначала после `home`, а потом после `home.owner` . Это разные объекты. Один мы назвали `home`, другой `owner`. То, что один написан внутри другого, не означает, что это один и тот же объект. Второй объект - это владелец дома. Владелец где находится? В доме. У владельца есть что? Дом. В котором он находится. В котором есть владелец. У которого есть дом. В котором он находится. Вот и цикличность.